# ¿Por qué con la nueva actualización GA4 no me aparecen los datos del año pasado?

Tags: data, error404, google-analytics, informes

Con la nueva actualización, hay datos que han desaparecido de mi Analytics, ¿por qué puede ser?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué datos deberían aparecer y no aparecen? ¿Qué tipo de consulta estás haciendo? ¿De qué rango a qué rango de fechas? En tu pregunta faltan detalles, pulsa en [edit] para completarla.